# X11: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: :0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ssh, remote

I want to open GUI applications (xeyes, firefox, xlock etc) on remote computer by using SSH from Local computer to connect to remote computer. 
Local PC--> SSH to --> Remote PC
I have two computers. I use one computer that I like the most. Let's call it "main" or "local".
Second computer is just a doll for me, lab to test my experiments on. Let's call it "guinea pig" or "remote".

I have a problem, that has been with me for so long. I don't know how to fix it. Example:

```
ssh -p 22 IP address
xclock (shows clock on local PC [main])
who
student102 tty7         2019-02-13 10:54 (:0)
admin pts/2        2019-02-13 13:23 (IP address)
export DISPLAY=:0
xclock (Error: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: :0
```

I have tried **ssh -Y** and **ssh -X** and same result. Same error.
What should I do? Reinstall Ubuntu? Reinstall SSH and Xorg? How can I fix this error?

Comment: It looks like you are SSHing as user `admin` - but trying to run `xclock` on a display owned by user `student102`?

Comment: Yeah. I figured that export DISPLAY=:0 or whatever student102 uses works but I get this error.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem. I added passwords to students with `sudo passwd username`
After that, I tried to get into user environment by using `ssh username@ip`, then I did `who` and saw the `:0` or `:1` as a display number. I used `export DISPLAY=:0` or `:1` then I ran `xeyes` command and HEYYYYYYY, IT WORKED! (Pardon my excitement)

I used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ssh-won-t-login-permission-denied-publickey-password) website.

It gave me a hint about what to do next.

Comment: I had to login first as the user at the graphics station tty7 with `sudo su - username`, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of the reasons you could get the following error:

> Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: :1

Make sure you are running any GUI process from the same user where vncserver process is owned by.

For example:

```
venkat@home-laptop:~/Downloads/$ ps -eaf | grep vnc
venkat    3504     1  0 Apr06 ?        00:09:52 /usr/bin/Xvnc :1 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -desktop home-laptop:1 (venkat) -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11//misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11//Type1 -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/venkat/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5901 -rfbwait 30000
venkat   10595  8391  0 02:33 pts/5    00:00:00 grep --color=auto vnc
venkat@home-laptop:~/Downloads/$
venkat@home-laptop:~/Downloads/$
venkat@home-laptop:~/Downloads/$ sudo -i
root@home-laptop:~#
root@home-laptop:~# xclock
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: :1
root@home-laptop:~#
root@home-laptop:~#
root@home-laptop:~# exit
logout
venkat@home-laptop:~/Downloads/$
venkat@home-laptop:~/Downloads/$ xclock
```

So run both the vnc server & gui process as same user as possible from local ssh terminal.